# Is there a way to determine absolute cell reference while in a named range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two named ranges that overlap one another. While I'm looping down the rows of `Range1 (A3:Z20)`, I need to also loop across the columns of a smaller portion of `Range1`, so I created `Range2 (G1:K20)`.

What I'm looking for in looping through `Range2` is if there is an "X" in any of the columns of the current row of `Range1`, I need to get the column's heading, which is why `Range1` ignores rows 1 and 2, but `Range2` does not.

My code sort of looks like this:

```
For intRowCntr = 1 To Range("Range1").Rows.Count
    For intColCntr = 1 To Range("Range2").Columns.Count
        If Range("Range1").Cells(intRowCntr, %intColCntr%) = "X" Then
            'Do a bunch of stuff here.
        End If
    Next intColCntr
Next intRowCntr
```

I marked the `%intColCntr%` with `%` to point out where I need the magic to happen.  Obviously the `%intColCntr%` won't work the way it is because it'll be `column 1` in Range2 but `column 7` in `Range1`.

This is as simple as I can think to make an example and hopefully someone can see what I'm getting at.  Basically I need to know where I am in relation to `Range1`, while looping through `Range2`.  An acceptable alternative is knowing where I am on the Worksheet itself in both `Range1` and `Range2`, and then working out the details on the worksheet level, before returning to the range loops.

Any advice would be appreciated!

:EDIT:
So I guess I didn't explain well enough, or maybe what I'm doing is overly complicated for what my goal is, so here's more of the story:

I'm trying to populate several listboxes of options that apply to a product.

So imagine Range1 is a list of cars, and Range2, Range3, Range4... are all groups of options that COULD apply to every car in Range1.  So Range2 would be colors, Black, White, Red, Yellow, etc...  Range3 might be Trim options.  Range4 might be body styles, and so on.

Now, I need the user to pick a car (Dodge Dart on Row 5).  Now I need to go through Range2 looking for an "X" that denotes which color choices are available to a Dodge Dart.  If I find an "X", I need to then grab that column's heading and drop it into a "Colors" listbox control.

I obviously can't just hit every column in Range1 looking for an "X" as every option group has it's own Listbox.

With a bigger picture of what I'm trying to do, is there some way of using Intersect that would make more sense?

Column would work, but I think it would require me to keep track of another set of variables that apply to locations on the Worksheet rather than just the two ranges.  It would work but it would be fairly clumsy I think.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear, but I think the `Intersect` property, which returns a range that's the intersection of other ranges, might be of use. Also, the `Column` property returns a cell's column number within the entire sheet.

Comment: I updated my description to better show what the point of it all is, thinking maybe I was too abstract?  Anyway, using Intersect could work.  My issue then would be ensuring I'm on the appropriate row of Range1.  I'll play with Intersect and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Like Doug, I'm not entirely sure what you want to do:
And like Doug, I'm looking on `Intersect Function`.
So try this:

```
Dim cel As Range

For Each cel in Range("Range1")
    If Not Intersect(cel, Range("Range2")) Is Nothing Then
        If cel.value = "X" Then
            'do your stuff here
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I used `For Each Lopp` rather than your conventional `For-Next Loop` so I can easily use the `Intersect`.
Hope this helps you a bit or maybe solve your problem.

**Version2 of above:**

```
Dim cel As Range

For Each cel in Intersect(Range("Range1"),Range("Range2"))
    If cel.value = "X" Then
        'do your stuff here
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to go with just using the Column property.  It was far too tedious with the Intersect.

Here's a code snippit of how I made this work:

```
        '...Lots of code looking at the first 4 Array elements...
            intHoldCol = Range("Range2").Cells(1, 1).Column
            For intColCntr = intHoldCol To intHoldCol + Range("Range2").Columns.Count
                If Len(Range("Range1").Cells(intRowCntr, intColCntr)) > 0 _
                  And Cells(1, intColCntr).Value = arySelected(4) Then
                    bolTest = True
                End If
            Next intColCntr
        '...Lots more code...
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: +1 for solving and sticking with your logic. Apologies if I can't comprehend what you're trying to achieve. :)